# sql query complex ordering by issue

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I'm having problems with an SQL query. If I wanted output the table so that it displayed the products from latest comment made to earliest comment made...keeping in mind that if the output is product id 78, product id 79, product id 81, product id 78, product id 81, i want the output to be product id 78, product id 79, product id 81. Basically i'm trying to create a page showing the latest comment activity on a product.

```
SELECT comments.products_products_id, products.name, products.minilocation, products.users_user_id, 
comments.comment, comment_id, comments.time_stamp, users.username, users.miniavatar  FROM products
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.products_products_id = products.products_id INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.products_users_user_id
ORDER BY comments.time_stamp DESC
```

Comment: Is comments.products_products_id actually comments.products_id?

Comment: So you want to order by latest comment, making sure all comments for an item stick together?

Comment: ya all the ids are correct. yep basically just want the to put the product with the latest comment activity on top. dont want any duplicates for product ids

Comment: i've tried putting group by to product id, but that doesnt give me an order with latest comment activity on a product

Comment: Wait - you've said two conflicting things. From your question, I gathered you wanted to show *all* comments, making sure that all comments for a particular product are together, and ordering the products by the latest comment.  But your comment suggests you want *just* the greatest comment per product_id and discard all other comments. Which do you want?

Comment: just want the products in order from latest comment activity to earliest. im gonna do pagination on products and pagination on the comments. so rather have a separate query for receiving the comments

Comment: i shouldnt have indcluded comments in the select query. that's my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if you just want the most recent comment per product_id, or if you want all comments, but just sorted by product_id where the product with the latest comment is first.

---

If you want *all* comments, grouped by product_id, where the product_ids are sorted in order of latest comment (i.e. see how the latest time stamp order suggest the products are in order (3,1,2):

```
product_id    comment_timestamp  
   3              2012-03-13
   3              2012-03-09
   3              2012-03-01
   1              2012-03-12
   1              2012-01-01
   2              2012-03-11
```

Then here's how you can do it -- find out the latest timestamp per product, JOIN that onto your main query, and order by it:

```
SELECT comments.products_products_id, products.name, 
       products.minilocation, products.users_user_id, 
       comments.comment, comment_id, comments.time_stamp, 
       users.username, users.miniavatar  
FROM products
-- NEW JOIN:
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(time_stamp) as latest 
            FROM comments 
            GROUP BY product_id) latest 
      ON latest.product_id = products.product_id
-- as before.
INNER JOIN comments ON comments.products_products_id = products.products_id 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.products_users_user_id
-- NEW SORT:
ORDER BY latest.latest DESC, comments.time_stamp DESC
```

The new table joined to is the maximum (i.e. most recent) time stamp per product id.
This will be the same within a single product id.

We sort by this first (to sort by the latest comment timestamp), and *then* sort by individual comment timestamp *within* each product id.

---

If you want the most recent comment per product_id, i.e.

```
product_id    comment_timestamp  
   3              2012-03-13
   1              2012-03-12
   2              2012-03-11
```

Then use:

```
SELECT comments.products_products_id, products.name, 
       products.minilocation, products.users_user_id, 
       comments.comment, comment_id, comments.time_stamp, 
       users.username, users.miniavatar  
FROM comments
-- NEW SELF-JOIN
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON comments.products_products_id = c2.products_products_id
                     AND comments.time_stamp < c2.time_stamp
INNER JOIN products ON comments.products_products_id = products.products_id 
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = comments.products_users_user_id
-- new condition
WHERE c2.time_stamp IS NULL
ORDER BY comments.time_stamp DESC
```

This sort of query is called "greatest n per group", and you basically join your COMMENTS table to itself *within* each product_id. You also join it such that one table has time_stamps less than the other's. The `WHERE` condition selects rows such that there is no greater time stamp for that product_id, i.e. the latest comment.

Comment: i think it worked. other than comment_id being ambiguous which i then changed to comments.comment_id. My most complex query yet. Thank you.